# What is the meaning of ‘heart wears thin’?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

> If your heart wears thin I will hold you up. And I will hide you when it gets too much.

This is from a song. I couldn’t really find a definition of *heart wears thin.*

Comment: It means losing confidence, strength, or the will to carry on, as the context shows: If your heart wears thin / I will hold you up / And I will hide you / when it gets too much / I will stay beside you / Nobody will break you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is ***[wear thin:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wear+thin)***

> 1. Be weakened or diminished gradually, as in *My patience is wearing thin. [Late 1800s]*.
> 2. Become less convincing, acceptable, or popular, as in *His excuses are wearing thin. [First half of 1990s]*
>
> ***Both usages transfer the thinning of a physical object, such as cloth, to nonmaterial characteristics.***

(AHD)

In your sentence heart means courgage, and wearing thin  means  “lose heart.”